# Get Google Refresh token from existing user auth code

Tags: android, node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth

I'm trying to get the Google Refresh token, the thing is that i haven't seen my current scenario anywhere, what i'm trying to accomplish is get the refresh token from a user auth token already generated by a google sign in from a native android app, basically i request every google permission i need on the app, and the the auth code from the sign in, with that auth code i send it to my Firebase functions backend, there i try to get the refresh token but i always get invalid_grant from google, so i don't know where could i be messing up

I saw that requesting oauth offline may solve the problem, but i'm sign in in the android app, so i cannot make a sign in request offline from the backend, i need the sign in and authentication to be only on the android app and i need this to make Google assistant requests over the backend and for this, the only thing missing is the refresh token

I have my google oauth2 key from google cloud console and the client initialized

```
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

var _client_id = require('./config/secrets/omni.json').installed.client_id; 
var _client_secret = require('./config/secrets/omni.json').installed.client_secret;
var redirect = require('./config/secrets/omni.json').installed.redirect_uris[1];

return new OAuth2(
        _client_id,
        _client_secret,
        redirect
        );
```

And finally try to get the token:

```
function getRefreshToken(authCode, idFBUser) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        getOAuthClient().getToken(authCode, function(err, token) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log(`Get Token success, token: ${token}`);
                getOAuthClient().setCredentials(token);
                saveRefreshFirebase(idFBUser, token)
                resolve(token);
            } else {
                console.log("Get Token error", err);
                reject(err);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

the error i'm getting exactly is this one:  { error: 'invalid_grant', error_description: 'Bad Request' }

The method i use in the android app to request the auth code is this one:

Creating the GoogleSignIn instance

```
val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .requestId()
            .requestIdToken(getClientId())
            .requestServerAuthCode(getClientId())
            .requestScopes(ASSISTANT_SCOPE)
            .build()

googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)
```

Calling the Sign in Intent:

```
val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RESULT_GOOGLE_SIGNIN)
```

Handle the Sign in Result:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            when (requestCode) {
                RESULT_GOOGLE_SIGNIN -> {
                    val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
                    try {
                        task.result?.let {  account ->
                            val id = account.id
                            val idToken = account.idToken
                            val authCode = account.serverAuthCode
                            Log.d("GoogleSignIn", "ID: $id")
                            Log.d("GoogleSignIn", "ID Token: $idToken")
                            Log.d("GoogleSignIn", "Auth code: $authCode")
                            btnLogin.text = "Sign Out"
                            loggedIn = true
                        } ?: Log.e("GoogleSignIn", "Exception: ${task.exception}")
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Log.e("GoogleSignIn", "Catch Exception: $e")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and the authCode is the one i used to try to get the Refresh Token in the backend

Comment: Can you post the code that requests the auth token in your android app?

Comment: @dj_rydu question updated! i add the code i use in the android app

Comment: @AndresRodriguez, which package have you used for google apis in Firebase Project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call

```
            .requestServerAuthCode(getClientId(),true)
```

instead of

```
            .requestServerAuthCode(getClientId())
```

If you want to get a refresh token. The javascript code you posted works with refresh tokens.

This is the easiest way to authenticate your app because all other kinds of token will expire. Refresh tokens dont expire. The Google Sign in library gives you an access code which you are already using to obtain a refresh token. You need to save this refresh token and send it to Google in order to obtain access tokens. The access token can then finally be used to make API requests.

By the way, that is actually what 'offline access' refers to. Took me a while to figure this out as well.

Comment: you mean requestServerAuthCode? because requestIdToken doesn't let me add a Boolean parameter

Comment: now i tried with that auth code and first it returns me unauthorized_cliente, i tried again and it returns invalid_grant, any clue?

Comment: So the authorization code that you send to your server is only valid once, thats why you will always get invalid_grant on the second try. Sorry I got confused there. Updated my answer again. unauthorized_client could mean that the client id from the app and the server dont match or that you did not enable the permissions in the firebase console.

Comment: it worked! thank you! the clients id were different, checked everything but that

Comment: @dj_rydu, I am also trying to achieve this. Can you please tell me the steps to create the client_id, client_secret, and redirect URL?